# Translation of "same as original"

Tags: traducción, españa

I wonder what is the formal translation of "Same as original" in Spanish, mostly used for confirming a photocopy of a document is the same with the original one.

(that is to use in Spain).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact phrase used will vary in different countries, but normally it is something like:

> Es copia fiel

Or:

> Es copia fiel y exacta

And *del original* may be added at the end.

Comment: Viendo tu respuesta me doy cuenta que he visto esta frase en algún lugar y creo que es la estándar. +1, ¡muy bien!

Comment: At least in Spain, validated copies of an official document are indeed marked with this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The [translation](https://translate.google.com/#auto/es/same%20as%20original) of the expression ***same as original*** is:

> igual que el original.

Example:

> X documento es *igual que el original*.

However, another expressions that I've heard are:

- Copia original
- Copia radicada *(o notariada)*

Which indicates that the copy is valid for formal procedures and also for  authenticating the veracity *of the copy*. Examples:

> X documento es una *copia original*.
>
> Debe traer una *copia notariada* de X documento.

Comment: thanks for answer. but is this an official translation? i.e. when they stamp your documents, does it write "igual que el original"?

Comment: @oeda I'm not sure, I did read your question as a mere translation of the expression. A more formal expression that I've head is: `copia original` or even `copia notariada`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing photocopies of an official document, you sometimes need some kind of verification to show that it is indeed a copy of the original.

For this, you can make the photocopy in an administration office and ask for a "copia compulsada", "copia cotejada" or just "compulsa" ("cotejo" and "compulsa" is almost the same), which will be a normal photocopy with an official stamp.

> **[compulsa](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=2eImZzdR9DXX27DwqyTz)**
>
> 2. f. Der. Copia de un documento cotejada con su original.

Regarding what to write to verify that it is a valid copy, people normally add:

- stamp of the administration
- date
- name and signature of the person doing the copy

Sometimes (see for example [this document](http://www.ua.es/es/presentacion/gerencia/compulsas.pdf) from Universidad de Alicante) this word is added:

> cotejo

Comment: Yes but when they do "compulsa", what do they write ON the document? Stamp something like "igual que el original."? In my document I have a stamp says "same as original". So I have to translate this to Spanish.

Comment: @oeda not necessarily. There's no official standard for that. Some institutions just stamp their logo with a sentence along the lines of «we hereby certify that this document exactly matches the original presented at our premises», some do indeed stamp the word «compulsado» on it. Just search «sello compulsa» on Google Images and you will see a lot of different stamp models.

Comment: @oeda ok, I see. See my update